Which frame will hold the load better
Which frame will be better to hold the weight?(50x50 c-profile) My boss claims 45 degree is always desirable, but in this circumstance it looks like the lower angle is better.


it looks like the lower angle is better ... how did you reach this conclusion?

why are you asking?

to determine if you attempted to answer the question yourself

"Better" is not a specification.  If you do the math you'll see that the compression of the support changes with angle, as does the bending of the horizontal member.  Not knowing the loads or dimensions of the system, you might not need a support at all.

@TigerGuy It supports a cable tray so its hard to specify the load. currently the load bends the c-profile down 5 cm.

@TigerGuy and the load placement is very close to what I drawn.

@jsotola. If had the maths or software to do it i would.

you guys are a helpful bunch.

It would help if you specified more information, like all the dimensions, materials and loads. If we have to guess these, the answer (if you get any) might be far from useful. If you are not sure about the loads, even information like the one you have provided in the comments, i.e. the bending the (presumably unsupported) profile down 5 cm is useful and you can add it to the question using edit.

For a rough estimate let’s say the weight of the frame members are negligible compared to the load.
Let’s call load P at the center of the brown tray in your diagram at a distance L from the top left support on the wall and the vertical distance between the bracket’s support at wall H.
If we assume the bracket is rigid there are some constant reactions that are independent of angle of the brace.
Those are the shear at bolts or screws connecting the bracket to the wall ant tension force on top bolt and compression force on the bottom.
$$ \Sigma M=0. \ \ PL-TH =0 \ , \ T=C=PL/H $$
$$  V_{ top} = V_{bot} =P/2$$
And compression on the bottom brace is
$$ C_{bot}= PL/H *cos \alpha $$

V shear
Alph is the angle of the brace from horizon.

In these applications because the loading is not extreme it is acceptable to make the angle more than 45 degrees to keep the space under bracket more open.
However one must watch the bending moment on the top member.
If we call the length of top member cantilevered from the corner of the  right joint of the bracket in case A, L2, the bending moment will be
$$ M=PL2.$$
